# Convert grouped strftime time to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, strftime

I have this code (I'm going to pass it as JSON data for highchart JS)

```
<%= ItemSale.pluck(:item_id).uniq.map{|item_id| {
name: Item.find(item_id).name, 
data: @item_sales.where(item_id: item_id).group_by_day(:date_sold,
format: "%s").count.to_a}}.to_json %>
```

That returns:

```
[{"name":"Computer","data":[["1456790400",2],["1456876800",0],["1456963200",1]]},{"name":"Android Phones","data":[["1456876800",3],["1456963200",0],["1457049600",1],["1457136000",0],["1457222400",0],["1457308800",2]]}]
```

However, I need this:

```
["1457049600",1]
```

to be an integer and multiplied to 1000 like this:

```
[1457049600000,1]
```

I tried doing sample data to make sure that it is correct and it is working:

```
@item_sales_series = [{"name":"Computer","data":[[1456790400000,2],[1456876800000,0],[1456963200000,1]]},{"name":"Android Phones","data":[[1456876800000,3],[1456963200000,0],[1457049600000,1],[1457136000000,0],[1457222400000,0],[1457308800000,2]]}].to_json
```

Is it possible or is there a way to

```
group_by_day(:date_sold, format: "%s").count.to_a
```

to output integer instead of string and also multiply it by 1000?

I use the group date gem to group my data by dates. Also I'm not using Highchart gems for this project, I'm trying different approach of inserting data into charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> array = [{"name":"Computer","data":[["1456790400",2],["1456876800",0],["1456963200",1]]},{"name":"Android Phones","data":[["1456876800",3],["1456963200",0],["1457049600",1],["1457136000",0],["1457222400",0],["1457308800",2]]}]

>> array.map{|hash| hash.merge(data: hash[:data].map{|str, int| [str.to_i*1000, int]})}
=> [{:name=>"Computer", :data=>[[1456790400000, 2], [1456876800000, 0], [1456963200000, 1]]}, {:name=>"Android Phones", :data=>[[1456876800000, 3], [1456963200000, 0], [1457049600000, 1], [1457136000000, 0], [1457222400000, 0], [1457308800000, 2]]}]
```

This works as follows:

```
#        ,-- Loop over every element of the top-level array and change it's value
#        |                 ,-- For each hash, change only the element called "data"
#        |                 |                      ,-- In the "data" array, change every element
#        |                 |                      |                   ,-- Change the string to an integer and multiply by 1000
#        |                 |                      |                   |
#        v                 v                      v                   v
>> array.map{|hash| hash.merge(data: hash[:data].map{|str, int| [str.to_i*1000, int]})}
```

Comment: Your a life saver! Thanks! I tried and it works!! :)